# What is difference between width, innerWidth and outerWidth, height, innerHeight and outerHeight in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, styles

I wrote some example to see what is the difference, but they display me same results for width and height.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var div = $('.test');
                var width = div.width(); // 200 px
                var innerWidth = div.innerWidth(); // 200px
                var outerWidth = div.outerWidth(); // 200px

                var height = div.height(); // 150 px
                var innerHeight = div.innerHeight(); // 150 px
                var outerHeight = div.outerHeight(); // 150 px
            });

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .test
            {
                width: 200px;
                height: 150px;
                background: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example you can see that they output same results. If anyone know what is the difference please show me appropriate answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the jQuery documentation?

Comment: Try adding padding, border and margin to your `<div>`, and see if that gives different results ;)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/   That page describes them all, and if you click each gives even more information.

Comment: I have searched in google, but none of the answers satisfy my expectations.

Comment: @BradM - No man. But results for "difference between width, innerWidth, outerWidth jquery" nothing tells me in essentials.

Comment: The first and second results are from stackoverflow. This question I explained in detail what I need and I didn't find some question like this. I did't say that similar question isn't post here, but I would like to defined in detail my question, so someone can have benefit from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 351, accepted):

Did you see these examples? Looks similar to your question.

[Working with widths and heights](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/dimensions/working-with-widths-and-heights/)

[image]

[jQuery - Dimensions](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dimensions.asp)

[jQuery: height, width, inner and outer](http://www.midnight-coding.com/2012/09/jquery-height-width-inner-and-outer.html)

Comment: best answer ever

Comment: I've just posted an answer below since right now I'm seeing a different behavior between the two options that is not infered by your description

Comment: `innerWidth` is less inner than `width`, go figure.

Answer (score 25):

As mentioned in a comment, [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/) tells you exactly what the differences are. But in summary:

- innerWidth / innerHeight - includes padding but not border
- outerWidth / outerHeight - includes padding, border, and optionally margin
- height / width - element height (no padding, no margin, no border)

Answer (score 6):

- width = get the width,
- innerWidth = get width + padding,
- outerWidth = get width + padding + border and optionally the margin

If you want to test add some padding, margins, borders to your .test classes and try again.

Also read up in the **jQuery docs**... Everything you need is pretty much there

Answer (score 5):

What I am seeing right now is that `innerWidth` includes the whole content

This is, if the window is `900px` and the content is `1200px` (and there's a scroll)

- `innerWidth` gives me `1200px`
- `outerWidth` gives me `900px`

Totally unexpected in my eyes

*In my case the content is contained in a `<iframe>`

Answer (score 3):

It seems necessary to tell about the values assignations and compare about the meaning of "width" parameter in jq :
(assume that new_value is defined in px unit)

```
jqElement.css('width',new_value);
jqElement.css({'width: <new_value>;'});
getElementById('element').style.width= new_value;
```

**The three instructions doesn't give the same effect:**
because the first jquery instruction defines the **innerwidth** of the element and not the "width". This is tricky.

To get the same effect you must calculate the paddings before (assume var is pads), the right instruction for jquery to obtain the same result as pure js (or css parameter 'width') is :

```
jqElement.css('width',new_value+pads);
```

We can also note that for :

```
var w1 = jqElement.css('width');
var w2 = jqelement.width();
```

w1 is the innerwidth, while 
w2 is the width (css attribute meaning)
Difference which is not documented into JQ API documentation.

Best regards

Trebly

---

Note : in my opinion this can be considered as a bug JQ 1.12.4
the way to go out should be to introduce definitively a list of accepted parameters for .css('parameter', value) because there are various meanings behind 'parameters' accepted, which have interest but must be always clear.
For this case : 'innerwidth' will not mean the same as 'width'.
We can find a track of this problem into documentation of .width(value) with the sentence : "Note that in modern browsers, the CSS width property does not include padding"

Comment: Added twist: `.css('width')` is the same as `.outerWidth()` (that is, it includes the border as well as the padding) when [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with all the answers given above.
Just to add in terms of window or browser prospects `innerWidth/ innerheight` includes just window content area, nothing else, but

`outerWidth/ outerHeight` includes windows content area and in addition to this it also includes things like toolbars, scrollbars etc... and these values will be always equal or greater than innerWidth/innerHeight values.

Hope it helps more...