# $(window).height is different in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, window

I currently have a vertical scrolling website with multiple divs,

http://dirkdunn.com

there are 4 divs, so when targeting, I can do $(window).height / 4,

however, internet explorer looks at window height as the viewport, and not the whole scrolling screen, and in turn I get a screen with very small divs,

is there an equivalent to IE that I can use to that it will look at it like the other browsers?

Comment: First off, you're missing the DOCTYPE declaration, and because of that, your page is rendering in Quirks mode (see [Quirks Mode and Standards Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode)). jQuery is not tested nor supposed to work in quirks mode.

Comment: And `$(window).height()` returns the viewport height in all browsers (assuming standards mode). You may want `$(document).height()`, though your question is not completely clear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using using  `$(window).height` try using `$(window).innerheight` for more details  visit [this](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow). If you want to know more about height, innerheight, outerheight, outerheight(true) visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight)