# CSS - box model width

Tags: jquery, css, width, box

According to box model, the total width of the element is = content width + margin + padding + border.

If you define a div element, and add width=200, margin=3px, border=4px and padding=1px. then on querying in JS code using `$('div').width()`, it returns 200 and not the width according to formula.

Comment: jQuery's [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method *will always return the content width*. Try [`.outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) instead.

Comment: See: [What is difference between width, innerWidth and outerWidth, height, innerHeight and outerHeight in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [width();](http://api.jquery.com/width/) specifications. It returns the width without margin, padding and border.

If you want to include padding and border you have to use [.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) and if you want to include margin too you have to use [.outerWidth(true)](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try with [outerWidth( true )](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) insted of [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

`outerWidth( true )` will returns the width of the element, along with left and right padding, border, and optionally margin, in pixels.

> using $('div').width(), it returns 200

This is excepted result.

If you want to get the width according to formula you have to try with `outerWidth( true )`

```
$('div').outerWidth( true )
```

Answer (score 1):

`.outerWidth(true);` should work as desired

[image: Outer width]