# Jquery .width() is not giving the right width size

Tags: jquery

I have the folowing html code:

```
<div id="first-tab-cont"> <!-- first tab content start here -->
 <ul id="slider">
  <li>elso 01</li>
  <li>elso 02</li>
  <li>elso 03</li>
  <li>elso 04</li>
 </ul>
 <a href="javascript:;" id="back">&lArr;</a>
 <a href="javascript:;" id="forward">&rArr;</a>
</div> <!-- first tab content end here -->
```

The `#first-tab-cont` and his parent `div` also, is set to `display:block; visibility:hidden;` but the jquery code: `var Max = $("#first-tab-cont #slider").width();` is not reporting back the correct width size.
I made an `alert(Max)` to I can see the reported value, and it's 960 (like I set to his parent in CSS code). But the `#slider` width is flexible, in order of how many `<li></li>` is on it. Each `<li></li>` is fixed 300px width.
I need to know the `#slider` width for scrolling the `li` elements only to that size.
Can someone help me out, to we can figure out why the `.width()` is not reporting the right size?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight
maybe this will help

Comment: If you've set a width of 960px for `#slider` then no, it's not 'flexible' and will stay at 960px wide.

Comment: the `#slider` width is auto, his parent set to 960px!

Comment: Okay that wasn't clear. Could you please create a live demo to show us your issue?

Comment: I made a code sample here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mt9n199g)

Comment: $("#slider").outerWidth(); you have some left padding there

Comment: I know what is the difference between `width()` and `outerWidth()`, but not this is the problem, now it's reporting 1000px, but if I put one more `<li></li>` it's still reporting 1000px, and it's should 1300px (because each `<li></li>` has a fixed 300px width).