# How to get complete body width with inner elements padding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this page which contains a table with 10-12 values , each table cell (`td`) has some `padding(10px)`. What is the best way to get the width of body including the width of this table containing the `padded cells.`

I tried using

```
window.innerWidth(true)
              element.containerWidth
```

In JS but it return me the width of body without the padding of inner elements.

and width:100% in CSS. Nothing Worked.

Edit: 
    Even after using outerWidth(true) , it just takes in the viewable area and not the total area or the scrollable width . How can the scrollable width be taken ?

My code is

```
<script>
    window.onresize = displayWindowSize;
    window.onload = displayWindowSize;

    function displayWindowSize() {
        Width = $('body').outerWidth(true);
        Height = $('body').outerWidth(true);
        $('#header-bar').css('width',Width);
        $('#exec2').css('height',Height);
        $('#exec2').css('width', Width);
        $('#exec1').css('width', Width);
        $('#exec1').css('height',Height);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `outerWidth()`

```
$('body').outerWidth()
```

Also you can get better idea of Width, OuterWidth, Inner by [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845094/2419644)

Comment: Even after using outerWidth() or outerWidth(true) , it just takes in the viewable area and not the total area or the scrollable width . How can the scrollable width be taken ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/)

In this scenario I would use
`$('body').outerWidth();`

If you ever need the margin to be included you can use 
`$('body').outerWidth(true);` instead

Comment: Even after using outerWidth(true) , it just takes in the viewable area and not the total area or the scrollable width . How can the scrollable width be taken ?

Comment: The problem occurs when resizing the window. it takes in just the reduce window width and not the total width one can scroll to.

Comment: @NischayGulati if your body width is smaller than the elements it houses, why don't you get the width from those elements instead?