# jQuery .width() function does not accurately return width of text within <div> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, polymer

I am trying to get the width of a line of text enclosed within a div tag. However when i compare the width value returned by jQuery's `.width`, it is different from the values shown by chrome's element viewer.

The console printed value is 238px, however the chrome's element viewer shows 283px

[image: dimension shown by chrome's element viewer]

The div tag is part of the shadow DOM of a custom polymer element, could this be the reason?

Is there any solution to this issue?

This is the tag for the line of text

```
 <div id = "label" class={{buttonLoc}}>{{label}}</div>
```

The javascript calling the jQuery `.width()` function

```
console.log($(this.$.label).width());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CSS jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/css/), specifying only the CSS value you want

```
var width = $('div').css("width"):
console.log(width);
```

Specifying only the first parameter gets the value, setting a second value in .css() will overwrite the value of the css property specified in the first parameter.

Maybe you have some [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) set which is changing the rendered value

Comment: The css jquery method returns the same value as the '.width()' method. I am pretty sure box-sizing had not been used

Answer (score 0):

You can also try innerWidth() / outerWidth() methods to obtain exact widths..

Just write :

```
 $('div').outerWidth():
```

A more detailed explanation can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight)

Comment: hmmm... it still give the same results. Thank you though

Comment: did you go through the attached link ??

Comment: Yup I did. I believe this must have something to do with polymer as it worked perfectly when the tag is used normally outside of the custom element's shadow dom