# Get Actual Width of Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a `div` with a class `myid_templates_editor_canvas-selection`.

```
<div class="myid_templates_editor_canvas-selection" style="position: absolute; font-size: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 377px; height: 174px;"></div>
```

It has a width of `377px`, but when I use the code  `alert($(".myid_templates_editor_canvas-selection").width());` , it returns `379px`. Why is it? I want to get exactly `377px`? What function should I use?

Comment: It will be because the element has 1px of padding or border on each side. As said above, `innerWidth()` will help.

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight

Answer (score 0):

It's because the div has 1px padding/border as said before in comments.
Try this: `alert($(".myid_templates_editor_canvas-selection").innerWidth());`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

var width = document.getElementByClassName('myid_templates_editor_canvasselection').offsetWidth;

alert(width);