# element height() not adding + 200?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to scroll to the end of the container. The element is having new items added via ajax on click, so I am recalculating its height each time I click to load more. The page scrolls fine but I would like to also add the navigation height in order to have the exact pixels. It looks like it is not adding `+ 224` tho

Html
    lorem

New items are added via a click and ajax.

Css

```
   nav {
     height: 90px;
   }
   #container {
      margin-top: 104px;
      margin-bottom: 120px;
   }
```

Jquery

```
var page = $("html, body");
var pos = $("#container").height() + 224;
page.animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000);
```

Comment: ops i was trying, question updated

Comment: Please show some HTML?

Comment: Try using `.outerHeight()` or `.outerHeight(true)` instead of `.height()`

Comment: are there 200 extra px of content on the page to scroll to?

Comment: I think you should use outerHeight(true) instead of height() like Andy's answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight

Comment: outerHeight(true) is still not working

Comment: you said it's added via ajax,maybe the problem is about it get height of container before the element is added. try getting container's height in callback of ajax and after you add the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this no ?

```js
var page = $("html, body");
console.log($("#t").height());
var pos = $("#t").height() - 500;
console.log(pos);
page.animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000);
```

```css
div{
  height: 1000px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use scrollIntoView for last added item

```js
  var j=0;
  function Add(){
  var item=null;
    for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
 j++
      item= $('<div class="item">'+j+'</div>').appendTo("#container")
 
 }
   item[0].scrollIntoView()
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="button" onclick="Add()" Value="Add" />
 <div id="container"></div>
```