# Unable to set iframe's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page, with an iframe that loads all the content. I have been trying to set the iFrame's height once that I frame has loaded.

This code is being run on the parent

```
$iFrame.load(function() {

    this.style.height =
        this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 30 + 'px';

    console.log('onload height', this.style.height);
});
```

Console gives me `onload height 1229px`

Yet if I run this on the page that loads the iFrame 
`window.document.body.offsetHeight`

It tells me `1535`

It's like its not getting the same values.

I setting the parents iframe using `$(function() {})` once the scripts have loaded

```
if(inIframe()) {
    $('iframe#page-content', window.parent.document).height( $(window).height() + 'px');
}
```

It gives me the same values as mentioned above, always seems to be off by 500 or more depending on the page

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight

Comment: Try:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight

Comment: The iframe's parent is the body and there is no css that sets a max height, although I do have a min-height of 1000px on the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$iFrame.load(function() {
  this.style.height = '100%';
  console.log('onload height', this.style.height);
});
```

Comment: Also, it might be because of a parent element being 1229