# Innerwidth in dartlang?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dart

Is there a way to calculate the inner width of an element in dart? I haven't been able to find a solution so far. JQuery offers the function .innerWidth() but I want to restrict this project to dart only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Element`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.19.1/dart-html/Element-class.html) class provides a number of properties of type [`CssRect`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.19.1/dart-html/CssRect-class.html). These are `contentEdge`, `paddingEdge`, `borderEdge` and `marginEdge`.

So in order to get the "inner width" (the width of the content and padding) of an element you can retrieve it with:

```
num innerWidth = element.paddingEdge.width;
```

Comment: I've tried this. Unfortunately it does not work. It gives the same result as Element.offsetWidth. Source: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/30a07d8332d2edd933f1056b88f5e054

Comment: 140 is the inner width of that element. Not sure what result you are expecting. `element.paddingEdge.width` is the same result as `element.offsetWidth` (which I believe is the same as doing `element.borderEdge.width`) because there is no border.

Comment: But how do I calculate the width without the padding?

Comment: Well in that case you use `contentEdge` instead of `paddingEdge`. But the jQuery function `innerWidth()` that you mentioned in your question includes the padding, so that's why I assumed you wanted to calculate the padding as well. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17845094/2712148

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped! I must've confused it with something else.