# How can I get actual height of application after rendering?

Tags: sapui5

How can I get the actual size of a view in SAPUI5 applications?

I tried:

```
this.getView().getHeight();
```

but it returns nothing. Also

```
this.getView().getWidth();
```

returns `100%` thus these 2 methods do not return the actual sizes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean the height of the whole application or the height of a specific view in your application? As views can be nested this is not necessarily the same and in your question you refer to the application a to a view.

Comment: I want to have the height of the <page> for example. I mean the area that every page render its items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getHeight and getWidth will return the property value, width of a view is set to 100% by default and height has no default hence the return values you are getting.

if you want the CSS dimensions you can try this...

```
this.getView().$().height()
```

and

```
this.getView().$().width()
```

you could also use alternate jQuery methods which will account for padding, border and margin - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight) for further explanation

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted. I actually want to get the height of the rendered page and then set the height of a customized item in SAPUI5.