# Why i am getting window.innerWidth higher than window.outerWidth and screen.width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to test my website on mobile browsers, But while testing i found that my `window.innerWidth` is giving me higher value than  screen.width & `window.outerwith`. I have tried on Chrome as well as opera, Firefox But no success.

Can somebody help me with what might be wrong here..

**Chrome results**

```
window.innerWidth: 980

window.outerWidth: 360

screen.width: 360
```

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight

Comment: did you put following line in the head of html: ` <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` ?

Comment: screen.width & window.outerWidth (360) represent  correct width of window ,

window.innerWidth( 980) contain scrollable or zoomable size to,


use this meta to prevent page zooming 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=480, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: Thanks @Sajan ....putting meta tag works.