# How to get coordinates of draggable and resizable elements using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, imagemap, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to generate multiple coordinates(left, top, width, height) for responsive image map. In an admin interface allows for create, movable and resizable rectangles on a image. I am able to multiple create, movable and resizable rectangles on image and saving coordinate values into database. In an user interface populating image map by using the database saved coordinates **but the rectangle positions are not showing correctly on both desktop and mobile browser view**.

**Here is my source code** [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sridharnetha/8mryxgf2/6/). After finishing the rectangle drawing on image, please click on Run button and mouse hover to image to check the rendered map area (rectangle).

```
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sridharnetha/8mryxgf2/6/
```

Comment: It is best to add *some* code to your post. This makes it easier for others to review the issue without having to follow a link to a fiddle.

Comment: To get `top` and `left`, you can use `.position()` or `.offset()`. For `width` and `height` use `.width()` or `.outerWidth()` and `.height()` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this post is a bit older, but here is an example I created a long time ago. Maybe it will help others with the same question.

[Link to the fiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/UfguFugullu/hnL1qcb1/)

The important snippet of jQuery to get the position and size of the element is here

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    // ...
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      console.log($(event.target).width() + " x " + $(event.target).height());
      console.log(ui.position.top + " x " + ui.position.left);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log($(event.target).width() + " x " + $(event.target).height());
      console.log(ui.position.top + " x " + ui.position.left);
    }
  })
  .resizable({
    // ...
    resize: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.size.width + " x " + ui.size.height);
      console.log(ui.position.top + " x " + ui.position.left);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.size.width + " x " + ui.size.height);
      console.log(ui.position.top + " x " + ui.position.left);
    }
  })
```

Further it's important to know the differences of `width`, `innerWidth` and `outerWidth`. [See more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight).