# Get the number of elements in the first row of a flex element

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, flexbox

As I asked in the title of the question, is there a way you can get the count of elements in the first row of a flex element?

Below is a picture showing my problem.

I need the amount of pictures before the first wrap (in this case 5), because I want to change the whole line (here 5 elements, but with a bigger screen maybe 7). How can I get this number? I really have no idea, so I hope you can help me.

If you want to see the code, let me know it in the comments.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Could you add the CSS for the Li elements as well please, it may help

Comment: Get the `width` of the container and the `width` of one element, then divide the container's width by the element's width and you'll get the number of elements in each row, and don't forget to count the `padding` and `margin` of the element and the container.

Comment: This seems to be an "[X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)". You could use media queries to do all of this for you. Maybe you are using media queries. Hard to tell when you show no code (other than what is in the image).

Comment: @RobMoll since he's tagging `flexbox` then he is probably using `flex-wrap: wrap;`, not necessary media queries.

Comment: I posted an answer to your inital question, but as pointed out by @RobMoll in a comment above this may be an X Y problem, so the question is why do you need this number, because that may mean you don't even need to be doing this computation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @AdilBimzagh's comment

> Get the width of the container and the width of one element, then divide the container's width by the element's width and you'll get the number of elements in each row, and don't forget to count the padding and margin of the element and the container.

Main function is `computeFirstRowItems`. It works by dividing the width of the flex-container by the outerWidth of a single item. See the [difference between width and outerWidth here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight#17845094)

```js
// See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight#17845094

// from http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/?ref=codebldr#outer_width_with_margin
function outerWidthMargin(el) {
  var width = el.offsetWidth;
  var style = getComputedStyle(el);

  width += parseInt(style.marginLeft) + parseInt(style.marginRight);
  return width;
}

// http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/?ref=codebldr#get_width
function width (el) {
  return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(el, null).width.replace("px", ""))
}

function computeFirstRowItems () {
  const ul = document.querySelector(".entry:first-child ul.img-list")
  const li = document.querySelector(".entry:first-child ul.img-list > li")

  return Math.floor(width(ul) / outerWidthMargin(li));
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  console.log(computeFirstRowItems());
});
```

```css
.img-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img-list > li {
  width: 25vw;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 25vh;
  margin: 0.7em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <ul class="img-list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<div class="entry">
  <ul class="img-list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It helped me a lot. =)